# Suspending a process instance

Tags: activiti

In my process definition, I have following:

> multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false"....

From this I understand that for multiple sets of input data, engine would create multiple instances of process definition which are then run in parallel.

From official documentation [page](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/):

> It’s also possible to suspend a process instance. When suspended, the process cannot be continued (e.g. completing a task throws an exception) and no jobs (such as timers) will executed. Suspending a process instance can be done by calling the runtimeService.suspendProcessInstance method. Activating the process instance again is done by calling the runtimeService.activateProcessInstanceXXX methods.

So If I suspend a process definition, would it impact other parallel running instances in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is for single process instance. i.e. the *process instance id* you provide in the method. You understood correctly, the engine will create multiple instances (each having a unique process instance id) which can be individually suspended later on.